# Looking for better structure for tree-like data

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have an expandable tree (in HTML page):

```
+ Category 1
- Category 2
  + Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
    |- Foo
    |- Bar
    |- Link 42
```

which is represented by a structure (defined in backend):

```
class Demo {
  static ImmutableList<Item> sample() {
    return ImmutableList.of(
        new Item("Category 1", ImmutableList.of(
            new Item("Some link title", "resource_id_1"),
            new Item("Another link title", "resource_id_2"))),
        new Item("Category 2", ImmutableList.of(
            new Item("Subategory 1", ImmutableList.of(
                new Item("Another link title", "resource_id_3"))),
            new Item("Subcategory 2", ImmutableList.of(
                new Item("Foo", "resource_id_1"),
                new Item("Bar", "resource_id_2"),
                new Item("Link 42", "resource_id_42"))))));
  }
}
```

with `Item` defined as follows:

```
public class Item {
  private String readableName;
  private String resourceId;
  private ImmutableList<Item> children;

  Item(String name, String resourceId) {
    this.readableName = name;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
  }

  Item(String name, ImmutableList<Item> children) {
    this.readableName = name;
    this.children = children;
  }

  public String getReadableName() {
    return readableName;
  }

  public String getResourceId() {
    return resourceId;
  }

  public ImmutableList<Item> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }
}
```

`resourceId` can have different readable names and can be placed more than once in whole structure, but only once in current category / subcategory.

Currently when users clicks on a link **or** writes URL the resource is loaded (ex. link *Foo* is mapped to `/showResource?id=resource_id_1:uniqe_magic_id`) and tree is expanded. It works only because of a hack - frontend creates its own copy of the structure appending some `:uniqe_magic_id` string to each resource id (each leaf) and when sending request to backend it stripes the magic part. `:uniqe_magic_id` is only used by frontend to expand proper items in tree shown above. It seems a slick solution to me (I was refactoring this code and removed `cleanId` method which I thougth wasn't necessary but was striping magic before sending request to backend...) and I'm looking for a better one.

I can modify both frontend and backend. I thought about some kind of tree with nodes like:

```
class Node {
  Node next;
  Node child;
  String readableName;
  String resourceId;
  String someUniqueHash;
}
```

and using `someUniqueHash`.

Is there better way to achieve same result without copying whole structure in frontend?

Comment: I don't think this will solve your issue, but since you need to enforce no duplicate values at any level, have you thought about using a LinkedHashSet (or Immutable thereof) instead of a List?

Comment: `List` is originally used here to indicate that it's sorted somehow and `Item`s don't have hashCode / equals so far, but it's a small (and useful) suggestion which doesn't actually solve my problem.

Comment: How about maintaining the structure at the backend only. Display a tree on the frontend and always ask for a subtree starting at the clicked node from the server? Also, using weakhashmap may be useful.

Comment: and may be fetch children for 1st level nodes too while you get a subtree for the clicked node.

Comment: What about change the child's id to start with parent's id through the `new Item(String, ImmutableList<Item>)` constructor? This way you will have unique id's, no need to copy or change the structure.

Comment: Could you please you post sample of your front end code?

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem. Do you want to eliminate excessive loading of duplicates or something else? If each `resource_id` does uniquely identify resource, why not to use an intermediate "cache" object to serve items to the list and request them from back-end on a miss?

Comment: @Stan the problem I have here is that `resource_id` does not uniquely identify structure in frontend, since it contains unique id of a leaf which can be located few times in whole tree (but it's unique locally among its siblings).

Comment: @Xaerxess, why not to use a path metaphor? You can add such a field into your client-side `item`, and automatically build path value for every item by "concatenating" parent's path and this item id. This is somewhat similar to the answer of `dasblinkenlight`, which actually added `uniqueId` into `item`, but the path value makes much more sense, because it allows you to select subtrees easily. "concatenation" is quoted because you can make it with numbers as well  (if your resource ids are numbers) by storing path components in a List.

Answer (score 3):

How about just asserting that the Item's id is locally unique for the menu that you are creating, and when children are appended to each item update a reference to the parent?

This will allow you to expand a subtree of whatever is focused in the url, the frontend (assuming html) will dynamically navigate the menu presenting the various categories to the user.

Local uniqueness of the items can be asserted through a factory pattern by adding a new class named *Menu* and making *children* in Menu mutable.

```
class Menu {
    final HashMap<String, Item> items = new HashMap<String, Item>();
    final List<Item> root = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Item createItem(String title, String id, Item parent) {
        if (items.containsKey(id)) {
            raise SomeRuntimeException();
        }

        final Item item = new Item(title, id, parent, this);

        if (parent == null) {
            root.add(item);
        }
        else {
            parent.addChild(item);
        }

        items.put(id, item);
    }

    /* default to have no parent, these are root items. */
    public Item createItem(String title, String id, Item parent) {
        return addItem(title, id, null);
    }
}
```

Some modifications to the Item class.

```
class Item {
    private final Menu menu;
    private final Item parent;
    private final List<Item> children = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Item(String name, String resourceId, Menu menu, Item parent) {
        ...
        this.menu = menu;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Item addChild(String name, String resourceId) {
        final Item item = this.menu.createItem(name, resourceId, this);
        this.children.add(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Now i sacrificed some Immutability because I believe that this pattern is much more expressive when handling errors than supplying a set of nested lists.

**Generating an immutable menu**

If immutability is a *big deal* you can always change Menu and Item into interfaces and implement immutable variants that copies the original Menu and Item, then add a *copyImmutable* method to the Menu class that will build the requested structure.

```
class MenuBuilder {
    /* ... contains all things previously declared in Menu ... */
    Menu copyImmutable() {
        ImmutableList<Item> root = ...
        ImmutableMap<String, Item> items = ...
        return new ImmutableMenu(root, items)
    }
}
```

This implies that you recursively do the same for all Item's.

**Algorithm for generating menu**

1. Lookup the item from the *Menu* class (handle potential errors)
2. Iterate every parent to that menu and record the ***pathTaken***.
3. When root node is reached, store that away as ***activeRoot***.
4. Iterate all root nodes in order from *Menu* and render them. When hitting ***activeRoot***, recursively render all children but only enter the ones registered in ***pathTaken***.

I hope this describes a solution that might give you inspiration in how to solve your problem!

Answer (score 3):

Making a copy of your tree in the front end is necessary, because it stands for a different concept: while the tree in the back end represents the *model*, the tree in the front end represents *a view of the model*. This is a very important distinction: the tree in the back end says what to display, while the tree in the front end says how to display it. Specifically, the front end knows what portions of the tree are expanded: back end should not know it, because the open/close state of the tree nodes will be different for different users.

Perhaps what you should do is to make the separation of duties explicit. Rather than making a copy of the tree and adding unique identifiers to its resource ID, make a separate class for `VisualItem`, encapsulating the ID of the actual item, and having a unique ID of its own (the unique ID would never go to the back end):

```
class VisualItem {
    String resourceId;
    ImmutableList<VisualItem> children;
    String uniqueId;    // Used only in the front end
    boolean isExpanded; // Tells you if the subtree is expanded or not
    // You can add more attributes here to avoid requesting the Item.
    // For example, you could add a readableName here
}
```

One way to ensure uniqueness of the IDs is to [use the `UUID` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html): it provides a very convenient [`randomUUID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) method, providing you with a unique identifier.

Comment: Basically the conclusion I've reached is what you write here - I cannot have (elegant) solution without making somewhat-similar copy of my structure in frontend. It's easier to add some unique id here (features like hashCode and equals for frontend structure suggested by someone else come free in this option) and in backed there will be only a simple model containing just plain data - no less no more. I'll post final solution later.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to reliably identifying an item's position in a tree structure given only a non-unique ID.

Are the generated URLs "permalinks", i.e. can the user safely bookmark them and come back in n years time when the tree structure might have changed? Will the tree structure's ever change? In particular, would you ever move a resource to a different category but expect its *old* link to take users to the *new* location?

**If the latter**, you've little alternative but to generate or specify a unique identifier for each resource ID. You could generate/use UUIDs, or have the user specify an ID and have code enforce uniqueness.

**Otherwise**, you can use the position of an item within the tree to give you a unique ID (since either the tree structure will not change, or users can't rely on a saved link to a resource working in future if a resource moves dramatically within the tree).

For example of the latter, given a tree:

```
- A
  |- Resource1
- B
  + X
  + Y
  - Z
    |- Resource1
    |- Resource24
```

So each item can be assigned a compound resource ID server side based on its position in the tree and its non-unique resource identifier. For example, "A/Resource1" and "B/Z/Resource1".

Or if you don't want to rely on the display name or assign IDs throughout, use the ordinal position of each category within its parent, for example "1/Resource1" (1st category, then Resource1) can be distinguished from "2/3/Resource1" (2nd category, then its 3rd child, then Resource1).

This is precisely what a vanilla filesystem does: identifies resources (files/folders) which don't have unique names, given a unique path to the item.

(Since the server side can do this assignment - add a Parent field to Item, then add a simple getUniqueResourceId() method which iterates up the tree via Parent links to compose a unique path + getResourceId(), and pass that out to the client rather than getResourceId() - an HTML frontend need not be affected.)